# How to make electron application run on MacOS versior lower than minimun supported version?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, slack

> For electron application minimum MacOS version supported is macOS
> 10.11 (El Capitan) according to offical [Electron Support](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/support) page.

[image]

My MacOS version is 10.10.5 so I am not able to run my electron application. But other electron based applications like [Slack](https://slack.com/intl/en-in/) and [Canva](https://www.canva.com/en_in/) are running fine.

How come slack and canva are running on `MacOS 10.10.5`? What should I do to run my electron application on this old version like slack and canca are running?

Answer (score 0):

You're likely running an older version of Slack. In the `Info.plist` for Slack I see:

```
<key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
<string>10.11</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

The minimum system requirements you're pointing to are for *building* an electron app. The resulting binaries will run on older versions of macOS

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy.